# Polymer Dom Repeat - Using Associative Arrays

Tags: javascript, polymer, associative-array, polymer-1.0

Is it possible to use Polymer `dom-repeat` with associative arrays like in the following code?

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{array}}">{{item}}</template>

// script
Polymer({
  ...
  properties: {
    array: {
       type: Array
       value: []
    }
  },

  ready: function(){
    this.set('array.someUID', 'someValue');
    this.set('array.someUID', 'someValue');
    this.set('array.someUID', 'someValue');
  }
});
```

I know that this example won't work, and when dealing with this problem, I've had to convert it to a normal array. But I would like to have the ID of the item in the array be the same as that in my database, allowing me, when the value updates, to simply call a function to update the item.

```
this.set('array.' + uid, newValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand `associative array` gets computed as `Object` in `javascript` and `dom-repeat` does not work on `Object`. If you redesign your data to something like

```
[{
  key:{{uid}},
  value:someValue
 }]
```

then you can use `dom-repeat` on it.